# Hover Submenu (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a hover submenu set up that is ALMOST working 100%.... only problem is that on page load the menu is not hidden. Once you hover it one time it works normally but I am trying to hide it on page load. Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.nav2').hide(); 
$(".nav").hover(function() {
$(this).find('.nav2').show();
}, 
function() {
$(this).find('.nav2').hide();
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a "display: none" style property to your .nav2 container